# Garbage value after decrypting Base64 encrypted String with RSA java

Tags: java, ios, encryption, cryptography, rsa

In my android application I am implementing RSA encryption decryption.

we have this app for ios as well as for android.

Whenever ios encryptes the message with my public key sends the encrypted text in base64 and on android side I decrypt it with my private key.

The problem is whenever I decrypt the data,It gives encrypted message surrounded by garbage padding

as shown bellow :

K������N�t �X�08���I�ii�z  �<���C�,r|�����aKj:N�^J���c��U�X�'�r�6Y��k,o�D^�)����F���[
����tH^�f�s��test updated pub key��

"test updated pub key" is the message.

```
        public static String RSADecrypt(final String result, Context context, PrivateKey key)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException,
        BadPaddingException, InvalidKeySpecException
{
    Log.d(TAG, "Decryption of " + result);
    String decrypted = "";
    try
    {
        byte[] b = Base64.decode(result, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Cipher cipher1;
        cipher1 = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        cipher1.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher1.doFinal(b);
        decrypted = new String(decryptedBytes,"US-ASCII");
        Log.d(TAG, "Decrypted text " + decrypted);
        Toast.makeText(context, decrypted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "Exception in decryption");
    }
    return decrypted;

}
```

I cannot understand where is the problem, on iOs side on android side or in converting bytes to string after decryption.Plz help

Comment: Take the base64 and string conversion out of the equation: look at the raw bytes you're encrypting, and the raw bytes after decryption.

Comment: But i want to transmit the data over server,so how will i transfer without converting it in base64.

Comment: I didn't say you needed to transmit it without using base64. I said that you need to *look* at the raw bytes you're encrypting and the raw bytes you're decrypting. And ideally try the same code without needing the base64 side (e.g. write to a local file and test it that way).

Comment: Can you please give me an example code.It is difficult for me to understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: I'm not talking about code necessarily. I'm talking about performing more diagnostics. You should look at the data before and after encryption, and the data before and after decryption. For a start, are you trying to decrypt the right number of bytes? How many bytes do you get back after decryption, and is *that* the right number? All of that can be done in a debugger. I would suggest you try to write a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem in a single application, however - ideally just in desktop Java rather than on mobile, as a starting point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try and use `"RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"` instead of `"RSA/ECB/NoPadding"` or similar for the value of `ALGO`. The surrounding random looking characters are actually random padding bytes. Padding is an integral part of RSA encryption and should not be skipped.

Note that the `KeyPairGenerator` should still use `"RSA"`, the generator is not concerned with modes of encryption and/or padding modes.

Comment: I tried this but this is throwingjava.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyPairGenerator RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding implementation not found

Comment: hey @owlstead thanx..It is working now..another problem we are facing is loading of private key from base64 string.whenever I try to get back my private key(generated on android) on ios from base64 ,It is throwing wrong tag exception but private key generated on ios is regenerated on my android side.we are trying many permutations but it is not helping.

Comment: Normally you don't distribute private keys - you generate them locally, then sign the public key
. This may be a difference in format (PKCS#8 vs PKCS#12) within the base 64 encoding. Best post an additional question and include the base64 encoding for both (using test keys of course).

Comment: @ownstead Thanx for the help..I changed the algorithm and every problem is solved,encryption decryption is working fine.Thanks a lot for the help.but On java it is taking 8 to 10 second for encryption..how can i make it faster.Im encrypting message with session key then encrypting the session key with receiver's public(Basically a PGP implementation),so how it can be faster?

Comment: There are a few major reasons for getting such bad timings: one is a random number generator that does not get enough entropy, RSA key pair generation. And large swaths of data of course. Normally you only create a key pair once in a while (and then you have to establish trust for the public key). So remove key pair generation out of the equation.

Comment: Yes im generating key pair only once...and use that keys everytime for encryption decryption..is there any way to speed up the process?8 to 10 seconds for sending a single message is not feasible..

Comment: Maybe your message is longer than that can fit into a single RSA encrypt. If this is the case then you should use hybrid encryption: create a random AES key, then encrypt the data, finally encrypt the AES key using RSA and send the wrapped key with the ciphertext.